# How to fix this error` “returned non-zero exit status 1”?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to solve a task, this is the task conditions

```
clean-archive

Create script clean_app.py that:

[ ] Take a zip archive name as an argument: python clean_app.py <zip-file name> 
[ ] Unzip the archive to a temp directory (using the appropriate Python library)
[ ] Remove folders that don't contain __init__.py. Only the root folder can be without __init__.py.
[ ] Add cleaned.txt with a sorted list of the removed folders. Folders should be listed with relative paths. One folder per line. For instance: example1\handlers\actions example3 … 
[ ] A folder without __init__.py has to be removed even if its child folders contain __init__.py. In this case, only the parent folder name has to be output to cleaned.txt.
[ ] cleaned.txt has to be added even if no folders are removed.
[ ] Create new archive with _new prefix (<old_name>_new.zip)
[ ] Add logging to the script.
```

I have wrote code which is working correctly in my computer, but when I submit it for test, the auto code system returns this error

```
Test name: test_clean_up

Failure message:

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['diff', 'tests/data/test1_out', 'test_new']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

This means that the output and the expected result is not the same. I asked about this problem organizers, they said that I must think about all possible folder structures.

Test is input, and new_test is output

[image: Test is input, and new_test is output]

This is my code

```
import os 
import sys 
import shutil 
import zipfile 
import logging 
 
def unzip_archive(zip_file, temp_dir): 
    """Extracts the contents of a ZIP archive to a temporary directory.""" 
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file, 'r') as zip_ref: 
        zip_ref.extractall(temp_dir) 
 
def collect_init_dirs(directory): 
    """Collects directories containing __init__.py files.""" 
    init_dirs = set() 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory, followlinks=True): 
        if '__init__.py' in files: 
            init_dirs.add(root) 
    return init_dirs 
 
def has_other_py_files(file_path): 
    """Checks if a directory contains .py files other than __init__.py.""" 
    dir_path = os.path.dirname(file_path) 
    for _, _, files in os.walk(dir_path, followlinks=True): 
        for file in files: 
            if file.endswith('.py') and file != '__init__.py': 
                return True 
    return False 
 
def remove_folders_without_init(temp_dir, cleaned_file): 
    """Removes folders without __init__.py files.""" 
    init_dirs = collect_init_dirs(temp_dir) 
    removed_folders = set() 
 
    for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(temp_dir, topdown=False): 
        for d in dirs: 
            dir_path = os.path.join(root, d) 
            if dir_path not in init_dirs and not has_other_py_files(os.path.join(root, d)): 
                shutil.rmtree(dir_path) 
                removed_folders.add(os.path.relpath(dir_path, temp_dir)) 
 
    with open(cleaned_file, 'w') as cleaned_txt: 
        for folder in removed_folders: 
            cleaned_txt.write(folder + '\n') 
 
def create_new_archive(temp_dir, new_zip_file): 
    """Creates a new ZIP archive with the cleaned directory.""" 
    with zipfile.ZipFile(new_zip_file, 'w') as new_zip: 
        for root, _, files in os.walk(temp_dir): 
            for file in files: 
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file) 
                new_zip.write(file_path, os.path.relpath(file_path, temp_dir)) 
 
def main(): 
    if len(sys.argv) != 2: 
        print("Usage: python clean_app.py <zip-file name>") 
        sys.exit(1) 
 
    zip_file = sys.argv[1] 
    temp_dir = 'temp' 
    cleaned_file = 'cleaned.txt' 
    new_zip_file = f'{os.path.splitext(zip_file)[0]}_new.zip' 
 
    logging.basicConfig(filename='clean_app.log', level=logging.INFO) 
 
    try: 
        logging.info(f"Unzipping {zip_file} to {temp_dir}") 
        unzip_archive(zip_file, temp_dir) 
 
        logging.info("Removing folders without __init__.py") 
        remove_folders_withoutsd_init(temp_dir, cleaned_file) 
 
        logging.info(f"Creating new archive {new_zip_file}") 
        create_new_archive(temp_dir, new_zip_file) 
 
        logging.info("Cleanup successful") 
    except Exception as e: 
        logging.error(f"Error: {str(e)}") 
 
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir, ignore_errors=True) 
 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

Can you say me a folder structure where this code may fail?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: make small example zips with their corresponding expected output and try to see if any difference occurs. Try to test lots of differents structures.